# Do aprotic solvents "slow down" SN1 reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, nucleophilic-substitution

> SOLVENT EFFECTS. Predict if using the polar, non-protic, solvent *N*,*N*-dimethylformamide (DMF, $\ce{Me2NC(=O)H})$ will speed up or slow down the following reactions and BRIEFLY justify your answers.
>
> **a**)
> [image: Ph3P + CH3CH2Br]
>
> **b**)
> [image: Ph3P + CH3CH2OEt2 BF4]

I have no doubt that **b**) takes $\mathrm{S_N1}$ pathway, but would DMF actually "slow down" this reaction? I want to be meticulous; I wonder if aprotic solvents "slow down" $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reactions or just regarded as not so ideal solvents for $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reactions. The wording of the question made me wonder.

Comment: SN1 with a primary cation intermediate is a no-no... You may want to reconsider. Anyway, what is the rate in DMF being compared to? Is it faster or slower than... what? This is a classic organic chemistry question and I can make a good guess at what the author is trying to ask, but it doesn't seem to be phrased in the best way. Also, before I can answer, we need to come to some agreement on what the mechanism is (because the answer depends on the mechanism), and I'm pretty sure it's not SN1.

Comment: @orthocresol I know and it is known that primary carbocations are unstable but I thought the one in (b) would be stabilized by BF4- anion. Since DMF, the aprotic solvent, wouldn't be able to dissolve negative ions well, I thought the BF4- anion will be freely hanging and stabilize the primary carbocation.